# Django REST API without using Database

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have an existing Django application. I need to include a functionality in it which doesn't involve DB.
I have written the operation to be performed in *views.py*

```
 class VamComponent(View):
    def getSectionADetails(self,request):
     .......
    return HttpResponse()
```

In *urls.py* I have included this line in urlpatterens:

```
url(r'^vamcomponent$', VamComponent.as_view())
```

I am able to access the details from this url  *http://localhost:8000/vamcomponent/* .

I need to have my endpoints with some value for section in the url like *http://localhost:8000/vamcomponent/SectionA* and *http://localhost:8000/vamcomponent/SectionB*.

In *views.py* if I modify the class to have 2 functions it,based on the value of section in the request it should call the respective method

```
 class VamComponent(View):
    def getSectionADetails(self,request):
     .......
    return HttpResponse()
    def getSectionBDetails(self,request):
     .......
    return HttpResponse()
```

How to make this change in *urls.py* file so that `getSectionADetails()` is called when the request has SectionA in it else `getSectionBDetails()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try like this:

First, you need to update the view so that it accepts a new parameter, ie `SectionA` or `SectionB`
    # urls

```
url(r'^vamcomponent/(?P<section>[-\w]+)/?$', VamComponent.as_view())
```

Now lets update the view accordingly, so that the value passed in urls goes to the view:

```
class VamComponent(View):
     def get(self, request, section=None):  # or post if necessary
         if section == "SectionB":
            return self.getSectionBDetails(request)
         return self.getSectionADetails(request)
```

FYI, if you are using `django-rest-framework`, then why don't you use [APIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/):

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class VamComponent(APIView):
    # rest of the code
```

Comment: If I use APIView, do I need to use the same url patterns as I do the View?

Comment: @Jayashree Yes, also it will allow you to use some functionalities such as permissions_classes,authentication_classes etc. More information are provided in documentation(attached with the answer)